# How can I tell exactly what line of code changes a given variable in C# with the Visual Studio 2017 debugger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I have a while(true) loop going, and there's a list that I update at the end of each loop, but I've been able to pinpoint a place where the list changes in the middle of the loop. However, there's no code that I've written which addresses said loop in that part of the code. The 2D arrays called test1 and test2 are different when I run the code, even though nowhere (I checked with ctrl+F) inside movePiece addresses boardHistory.

I want to somehow track this list so that when it changes I can see the call stack and the line which changed it.

```
while (true)
            {
                prompt();
                if (!moveSet.empty())
                {
                    inStr = moveSet.next();
                }
                else
                {
                    inStr = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
                }

                validInput = true;
                if (!inputIsValid(inStr))
                {
                    validInput = false;
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid input");
                }

                if (validInput)
                {
                    string[] arr = inStr.Split(' ');

                    int[,] test1 = boardHistory[boardHistory.Count - 1].boardValues;
                    movePieceTrad(arr[0], arr[1]);
                    int[,] test2 = boardHistory[boardHistory.Count - 1].boardValues;

                    if (!moveValid)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        turn++;
                        posOrNegTurn = -posOrNegTurn;

                        int w = tradToCoords(arr[1])[0];
                        int u = tradToCoords(arr[1])[1];

                        bool tempPawnBool = false;
                        if (Math.Abs(board[w, u]) == 1)
                        {
                            tempPawnBool = true;
                        }

                        int[] movement = {
                            tradToCoords(arr[0])[0], tradToCoords(arr[0])[1],
                            tradToCoords(arr[1])[0], tradToCoords(arr[1])[1]
                        };

                        bool tempCaptureBool = false;
                        int[,] test4 = boardHistory[boardHistory.Count - 1].boardValues;
                        int test5 = boardHistory[boardHistory.Count - 1].boardValues[w, u];
                        if (boardHistory[boardHistory.Count - 1].boardValues[w, u] != 0) // if the last board state had a piece where the last move landed
                        {
                            tempCaptureBool = true;
                        }

                        if (moveWasEnPassant)
                        {
                            board[w, u - board[w, u]] = 0;
                            tempCaptureBool = true;
                        }

                        moveHistory.Add(new Move(
                            Math.Abs(board[w, u]),
                            board[w, u] / Math.Abs(board[w, u]),
                            tempCaptureBool,
                            tempPawnBool,
                            movement
                            ));

                        moveWasEnPassant = false;

                        if (!(board[w, u] == 1 && u - tradToCoords(arr[0])[1] == 2) &&
                            !(board[w, u] == -1 && u - tradToCoords(arr[0])[1] == -2))
                        {
                            resetEnPassant();
                        }

                        int temp = board[w, u]; //the value of the piece just moved
                        int type = temp / Math.Abs(temp);

                        if (Math.Abs(temp) == 6)
                        {
                            if (type == -1) castlePiecesMoved[0, 1] = 1;
                            if (type == 1) castlePiecesMoved[1, 1] = 1;
                        }
                        if (Math.Abs(temp) == 4)
                        {
                            if (type == -1 && w == 0) castlePiecesMoved[0, 0] = 1;
                            if (type == 1 && w == 0) castlePiecesMoved[1, 0] = 1;
                            if (type == -1 && w == 7) castlePiecesMoved[0, 2] = 1;
                            if (type == 1 && w == 7) castlePiecesMoved[1, 2] = 1;
                        }

                        if (!aMoveExistsForType(posOrNegTurn))
                        {
                            if (posOrNegTurn == -1 && blackIsChecked)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("--White wins by checkmate--");
                                printBoard();
                            }
                            else if (posOrNegTurn == 1 && whiteIsChecked)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("--Black wins by checkmate--");
                                printBoard();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("--Draw by stalemate--");
                                printBoard();
                            }
                            //BoardObject tempBoardObject2 = new BoardObject(board, possibleEnPassants, castlePiecesMoved, posOrNegTurn);
                            //boardHistory.Add(tempBoardObject2);
                            break;
                        }
                        BoardObject tempBoardObject = new BoardObject(board, possibleEnPassants, castlePiecesMoved, posOrNegTurn);
                        boardHistory.Add(tempBoardObject);
                    }
                }
                printBoard();
            }
```

Comment: Maybe this helps [Set a watch on variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 0):

> I want to somehow track this list so that when it changes I can see
>   the call stack and the line which changed it.

I think you can [set a breakpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/using-breakpoints?view=vs-2019) at the top of the loop with the [Call Stack Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-use-the-call-stack-window?view=vs-2019) and [Watch Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/watch-and-quickwatch-windows?view=vs-2019).

When you start it, please set a breakpoint first and then choose **Start Debugging**. Under the process, the Call Stack window will show the the call stack and see its specific line.

**Besides**, when you continue execution across a breakpoint, when the call stack changes, the cursor is the affected line.

**Also**, you can use **Watch Window** to see the changes of the variables and as the breakpoint progresses, it directly reflects the subtle changes in your parameters.

Hope it could help you.